# Denwer не видит page

Tags: php

пишу социальную сеть на PHP (практика) и при проверке сайта, заметил, что не открывается авторизация и регистрация, они находятся в page, строчки выглядят так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть беда?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: что значит не открывается? смотрите ошибки в логах. `$page` искомое значение имеет перед этими ифами?

Comment: К вопросу наверное не совсем относится, но Вы бы заменили Denwer на что-то поновее, на Open Server например, с выхода последнего обновления для Denwer прошло 9 лет. Тут у PHP 7.4 Security Support  в ноябре заканчивается, а Вы все еще на 5-ке.

Comment: `var_dump($Page);` на той странице/шаблоне сделайте. Посмотрите, что выводится: ожидаемое или нет?

Comment: @Pr0gramm1st, я получил лог '-dxdebug.remote_enable=1',
    '-dxdebug.remote_handler=dbgp',
    '-dxdebug.remote_mode=req',
    '-dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1',
    '-dxdebug.remote_port=9003',

Comment: '-dxdebug.remote_autostart=1',
    '-dxdebug.mode=debug',
    '-dxdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1',
    '-dxdebug.client_port=9003',
    '-dxdebug.start_with_request=1',
    'z:\\home\\skbknagu.ru\\www\\index.php'
  ]
}

Comment: Это результат работы `var_dump($Page);`? Это не совсем тот лог)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)